# Disable Apple Pay/Wallet spam

Tags: apple-pay

How do I disable this annoying spam??

I've never used Apple Pay, nor do I have any intention of doing so. But apparently, after upgrading to an iPhone 6, Apple's gonna spam me every 24 hours?

There was some other garbage spam I had to disable too, but can't figure this one out... Pretty annoying that Apples so aggressively peddling their services these days. You'd think a simple opt in/out during onboarding would suffice.

Anyone have any ideas how to disable this? Thanks

[image]

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/310314/how-can-i-stop-iphone-prompting-me-to-setup-apple-pay-in-settings/322265#322265

Comment: Thanks for the heads up @bmike  That notification icon was indeed another annoyance I just hadn’t had a chance to investigate yet. Glad to have it removed now... However this question is not a duplicate. It was asked long before the referenced other question, and is not referencing the same issue.

Comment: Best to open a question on [meta] if this gets closed again. I get there's a fine line between disabling notifications and not enrolling, but these two might get unified / covered in a larger question over time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can disable the notifications for Apple Wallet. Settings > Notifications > Wallet. Toggle Allow Notifications to off.